# Execute a Job using T-SQL on a SSAS Cube

Tags: c#, t-sql, ssas, adomd.net

I'm trying to execute a SQL job using T-SQL in my application on a SSAS cube. Here is what I have got so far:

```
public void UpdateCube()
{
    AdomdConnection conn3 = new AdomdConnection("Data Source=BTN-SQL1;Initial Catalog=BTNTurboAnalysisServices;");
    conn3.Open();
    AdomdCommand cmd = conn3.CreateCommand();

    cmd.CommandText = "EXEC [SalesAnalysis].sp_start_job N'Process BTN SSAS'; GO";

    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

    conn3.Close();
}
```

[SalesAnalysis] is the name of my cube and 'Process BTN SSAS' is the name of my SQL job.

The error I receive is:

```
Query (1, 6) Parser: The syntax for '[SalesAnalysis]' is incorrect.
```

Any help would be appreciate, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

sp_start_job is a stored procedure in master.dbo
try

```
exec master.dbo.sp_start_job N'Process BTN SSAS'; GO";
```

Also, as master.dbo.sp_start_job is a SQL stored procedure, you'll need to use a SQL connection with ADO.NET (System.Database.SQLClient.SQLConnection) to kick it off, not ADOMD.
As sp_start_job just kicks off SQLAgent jobs, you'll need to make sure it's running as well.

There are some methods in ADOMD that allow you to process cubes, but I can't recall them off the top of my head.

Something like

```
   Server server = new Server();
    server.Connect(cubeConnectionString);

    Database database = server.Databases.FindByName(databaseName);
    Cube cube = database.Cubes.FindByName(cubeName);

    cube.Process(ProcessType.ProcessFull);
```

Comment: Hi there, I changed my command text to that and it returns: 
Query (1, 6) Parser: The syntax for 'master' is incorrect.

Comment: I'm not sure that'll work as I'm using ASP MVC 3, and it doesnt recognise Server server = new Server(); even when I use the namespace Microsoft.SqlServer;

Comment: I believe that uses AMO, which is a SSAS 2005 feature, I'm using 2008 which uses ADOMD, thats why it doesn't recognise it for me

Comment: I solved it by running an XMLA command similar to the one found here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms123481.aspx